# Android maps APIs

Tags: android, api, maps

I want to develop an android mapping aplication that enables users to navigate in the map:
my problem with using google maps API is that the area that I want to map is not detailed and I want to use the maps prvided by other server that has the map I want, or better if I could do it offline(the map is local and not from a server)

what are the best and easiest mapping API that are free licened, enable offline mapping, or enable using other server or OSM????

I found many API but these features I don't if they are supported, and I dont know what is the best(e.g mapquest api, decarta api, nutiteq api)

any help any opinion will be nice,
and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some of these libraries: [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/), [mapsforge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/). Both of them provides interface to some internet map databases and allows to create your own maps provider.

They allows you to have (and handle) your offline cache, dynamic asynchronous maps loading, resampling on zoom, adding overlays and so on, like original MapView does.
Another good point of using these libraries is that they are well-designed for in-place substitution of google MapView.

Both of them are LGPL (you can use them in you commercial apps) and provide interface for OpenStreetMap out-of-the-box.

Comment: i would recommend osmdroid as well

Comment: I tried both of them for my custom maps and find out that osmdroid doesn't handle map and cache in a proper way on zoom in and out. Also it is more complicated for use, so I'd like to recomend mapsforge

Comment: Thanks, I will check them out, 
I find mapping APIs for web application will it work on android or it should be developed from the beginning for android?